# Why is my array outputting one row

Tags: php

My $aExtensionObjects print_r fine shows all of the things in the array but $aExtensionName only seems to output one why?

```
$aExtensionObjects Array:

Array ( [0] => Extension Object ( [iID:private] => [sExtensionName:private] => 2147483647 [db:private] => MySQLiPluggin Object ( [sqliConnection:private] => mysqli Object ( ) [Query:private] => [getResult:private] => ) [bExisting] => 1 ) [1] => Extension Object ( [iID:private] => [sExtensionName:private] => 876378990 [db:private] => MySQLiPluggin Object ( [sqliConnection:private] => mysqli Object ( ) [Query:private] => [getResult:private] => ) [bExisting] => 1 )) ) Etc..

$aExtensionName Array:

Array ( [] => 989898 )
```

The code [ed: maybe?]

```
    $manExtensionManager  = new extensionManager(); 

    $aExtensionObjects   = $manExtensionManager->getallExtensions();

    $aExtensionName      = array();

for($iCount=0; $iCount<count($aExtensionObjects);$iCount++){
    $Extension = $aExtensionObjects[$iCount];
    $aExtensionName[$Extension->getExtensionID()] = $Extension->getExtensionName(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us your print_r output? (or some of it).

Comment: You need to use a `$` to denote a variable here `Extension = $aExtensionObjects[$iCount];` Turn on error reporting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  your `$Extension->getExtensionID()` always returns one id that's why array is just getting one item.

check out you function `getExtensionID()`

And also can you confirm you are missing $ and - to just typo mistake or you really forgot in your program.

You can confirm if you function `getExtensionID()` is not working properly by doing

```
$aExtensionName[]=$Extension->getExtensionName();
```

and `print_r($aExtensionName)` and see what is in it

Comment: My function is:

 public function getExtensionID(){
            return $this->iID;
    }    
        

I did print $aExtension and it showed the [0]->array

Comment: @Jess:Can you do it once in this way and check $aExtensionName[]=$Extension->getExtensionName();
print_r($aExtensionName);?

Comment: Array ( [] => 989898 [0] => 989898 )

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a dash --

```
$aExtensionName[$Extension->getExtensionID()] = $Extension>getExtensionName();
```

should be

```
$aExtensionName[$Extension->getExtensionID()] = $Extension->getExtensionName();
```

Comment: If one of these answers was what you were looking for, please mark it as answering your question.  :-)